# Trusted vulnerability database source

Tags: exploit, databases, vulnerability, cve

Would like to ask currently, is the National Vulnerability Database (NVD) still the place to go if you want to search for update vulnerabilities for different products? I find that some product vulnerabilities are not found in the NVD database. For example, I search for "[Sitefinity](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search-results?query=sitefinity&search_type=all&cves=on)" and it gives me no results. But when I do a search on Google, I found something on [osdir](http://osdir.com/ml/bugtraq.security/2015-01/msg00058.html). Is there another alternative vulnerability database that you know of that is more updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVD is an authoritative source for vulnerabilities *reported to them*. They do not list vulnerabilities that merely exist in the wild.

So, yes, the NVD is a fine place to go, but it is never going to be fully complete. Not every vulnerability is issued a CVE.

Comment: ok, so the only other way is to use the search engine. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a lot of vulnerability DBs out there.

In the good old days, those were Milw0rm and 0day.

Now you probably look at http://www.rapid7.com/db/
as well as https://www.exploit-db.com/